# Is the "Fanatic" badge awarded multiple times?

Tags: discussion, badges

As I already got one "Fanatic" gold badge. Is the "Fanatic" badge awarded multiple times at http://magento.stackexchange.com or any other community ?

Comment: You get it only once per site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you get the badge only once per site.

You can see this in the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168333):

> gold; awarded once

However, you get it for the main site and the per-site meta separately. In other words, the per-site meta has its own "Enthusiast" and "Fanatic" badges.